# Javascript: test if an operation inside a multidimensional array matches a number

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array:

```
var tasks = [
["First Task",1,0],
["Second Task...",4,5],
["Third Task!",0,5]
];
```

**Note:** the numbers next to the tasks are the minutes and the seconds that the person has to complete the task.

I want to test to see if any of these tasks have a certain number of seconds. Basically, I'd like to know if for any of the tasks, *the first number * 60 + the second number* is equal to `someNumOfSecs`. So, if `someNumOfSecs == 60` then the condition would return `true`, but if `someNumOfSecs == 58` it would return false. Again, I don't want to test for one specific task, but for the whole array. How would I do this? Thank you.

*By the way: I'm sorry if I wasn't very clear with my explanation, so if you don't understand something please comment.*

Comment: *"I don't want to test for one specific task, but for the whole array."* Just iterate over the array and make the comparison? What is the difficulty here or your specific problem? You can use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which is made for problems like this (i.e. "does the array contain an element that matches a condition"). If you are not familiar with the concept of iteration, I recommend to [learn about loops](http://eloquentjavascript.net/02_program_structure.html#h_FaGGgUI+MM) first.

Comment: I'm familiar with it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and see if any element matches what you're looking for.

```
var value = 60;
var match = tasks.some(function (item) {
 return (item[1] * 60 + item[2]) === value;
});
```

Comment: Your one seems to work but why do you put `item` inside the function parameters and how does that work exactly?

Answer (score 1):

```
var tasks = [
   ["First Task",1,0],
   ["Second Task...",4,5],
   ["Third Task!",0,5]
];

function getByNumSeconds(secs) {
   return tasks.filter(function(t) {
       return (t[1] * 60 + t[2]) === secs;
   });
}

console.log(getByNumSeconds(60)) // ["First Task",1,0]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the array that fulfills the condition you can use `Array.prototype.filter`:

```
function filterSomeNumOfSecs(someNumOfSecs) {
   return tasks
     .filter(function(task) {
        return (task[1]*60 + task[2]) === someNumOfSecs;
     });
}

filterSomeNumOfSecs(5); => [["Third Task!",0,5]]
```

Now if you just want the name of the task you can also use `Array.prototype.map`:

```
function mapSomeNumOfSecs(someNumOfSecs) {
   return tasks
     .filter(function(task) {
        return (task[1]*60 + task[2]) === someNumOfSecs;
     })
     .map(function(task) {
        return task[0];
     });
}

mapSomeNumOfSecs(5); => ["Third Task!"]
```